# How to avoid many to many relationships

Tags: database-design

Admittedly this is probably a simple question but I want to make sure I get this right:

I have 3 tables. There is a one to many relationship between Milkshake and Person (One person has many milkshakes). There is also a one to many relationship between Person and Coronary Care attendances (one person can go to coronary care many times.

This leaves me with a many to one to many relationship. Several links have told me that this is essentially a many to many relationship and that I need a link table but I am assuming the Person table is this link? also how would this cause an issue for queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you follow the entity-relationship model strictly as originally described by Peter Chen, you would have 5 tables - 3 entity relations and 2 relationship relations.

[image: Many-to-one-to-many ER]

[image: Many-to-one-to-many tables]

There is a transitive many-to-many relationship between `Milkshake` and `Coronary Care` via the two one-to-many relationships.  In this case, the `Person` table need not be involved - you could join `Owns` to `Attends` on the `Person` key they have in common:

```
SELECT milkshake_id, coronary_care_id
FROM Owns
INNER JOIN Attends ON Owns.person_id = Attends.person_id
```

Now, if you denormalize tables with the same determinant, you get the 3 tables you had in mind in your question:

[image: Denormalized tables]

In this case, the relationship between `Milkshake` and `Person` is recorded in the `Milkshake` table, and the relationship between `Person` and `CoronaryCare` is recorded in the `CoronaryCare` table.  (Remember that foreign key constraints are not relationships.)

You can still get the many-to-many relation:

```
SELECT milkshake_id, coronary_care_id
FROM Milkshake
INNER JOIN CoronaryCare ON Milkshake.person_id = CoronaryCare.person_id
```

As you can see, the `Person` table is not the link.  Even when denormalized, you still have two one-to-many relationships, except that they're now recorded in the `Milkshake` and `CoronaryCare` tables.

The sources you refer to that recommend a link table refer to direct many-to-many relationships, not transitive many-to-many relationships.  We don't need to record transitive relationships since we can generate them by combining two or more direct relationships.

Many-to-many relationships are a natural part of relational and entity-relationship data modeling and don't cause any issues in queries, as long as you understand them.